# Структура проекта FLASK и что посоветуете из актуальных модулей

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, socket.io, blueprint

Пытаюсь разобраться с темой создания проекта на **FLASK**. И в ходе появились вопросы:

1. Если разделять Роутинг, то это только **Blueprint**? Как-то можно в одном каталоге (пакете) собрать все роутинги и потом разом импортировать в app.py?
2. Для проекта хочу использовать **MySQl** базу данных. Мне рекомендуют **sqlalchemy**, а я пока пробовал только **flask_mysql_connector**. Я понимаю что это только коннектор, и запросы мы пишем в БД, а потом обрабатываем результат, но у этой ОРМ функционал практически такой же, только запросы пишутся немного иначе. В чём прям кардинальное отличие, где этот жирный плюс в сторону Алхимии?
3. Я так понял, что для взаимодействия пользователей на сайте (допустим чат) лучше всего использовать **SocketIO**? Если да, то можете направить на какой-нить курс или руководство, где объяснят чуть ли ни на пальцах для особо доходчивых. Буду благодарен
4. А где бы я мог посмотреть структуру какого-нить подобного проекта, который уже сочетает всё это? Да, многого хочу :-)
5. Как обезопасить конфигурационные данные? достаточно их записать в **.env** файл? а потом их просто вытащить через:

```python
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
DBIP = str(os.getenv('DBIP'))
```

Буду рад вашим советам и направлениям на путь истинный! ;-)

Comment: Слишком много вопросов, в одном посте должен быть один вопрос

Comment: Вопросы больше общего плана, которые не требуют какой-то большой доказательной базы для ответа, а хотелось бы получить ответ от специалистов, которые знают толк в разработке на FLASK, чтобы указали мне в правильном ли направлении начал плыть, пока не скрылся за горизонт... Мне не нужно цитировать википедию или официальную документацию - я это и сам могу найти. Мне сейчас важна оценка специалистов с высоты их опыта

Comment: @andreymal, так что этот вопрос хоть и кажется большим, но в целом можно ответить довольно кратко.